# imagemagick comosite proportion to image size

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to place year on picture with imagemagick. I have about 4000 pictures. I try to do it with imagemagick using the -compose parameter.

Logo is 200x67 px.

[image: logo]

But all pictures is not the same size. How i can add proportional size of year on each image?

Example image

[image: example image]

I not yet try imagemagick, but i placed logo to two different pictures with photoshop. 
Or imagemagick handles this? Or i can put text on each image with defined font size? Or better convert all images to one size? If that, can imagemagick tell me wich is smallest picture?

Comment: I made some script http://pastebin.com/ZDeZagmD and on my screen looks good. I try it on another laptop too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made script http://pastebin.com/HdBMx2Zm It looks good in my XP machine (ACDSee) and also on windows 7 (windows integrated image viewer). In some pictures year is little bit bolder, but it is ok.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# 
# 
# find /media/sf_test/meklee/ -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec /root/imagick_script.sh "{}" \;
#
# depends on jhead and imagemagick
# if call find from another file, then is possible to count all pictures, place count on file and in imagick_script.sh
# decrase that amount by 1. 
# 
# in script some directory names is in Latvian :)
#

backgroundimage=$1
bgp=/media/sf_test/


if [ -f "${bgp}stop" ]
then
    echo -ne "*"
    exit 0
fi

if [ ! -d "${bgp}2019" ]
then
    mkdir -p "${bgp}2019"
fi

# "%[fx:w] %[fx:h] %[exif:DateTime]" (use this if images has no exif data)
#dim=`identify -format "%[fx:.15*w] %[fx:.15*h] %[exif:orientation] %[exif:DateTime]" "$backgroundimage"`

# be careful with auto-orient
# see this: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#auto-orient
#orient=`echo $dim | awk '{print $3}'`
#if [ "$orient" != "1" ]
#then
#orient image (rewrite original)
#    convert -auto-orient "$1" "$1"
#re-read image data
#    dim=`identify -format "%[fx:.15*w] %[fx:.15*h] %[exif:orientation] %[exif:DateTime]" "$backgroundimage"`
#fi


# jhead is much faster...


#ww=`echo $dim | awk '{print $1}'`
#hh=`echo $dim | awk '{print $2}'`
#ww=`printf "%.0f\n" "${ww}"`
#hh=`printf "%.0f\n" "${hh}"`
ww=`jhead "$1" | grep 'Resolution' | awk '{print $3}'`
hh=`jhead "$1" | grep 'Resolution' | awk '{print $5}'`
ww=`echo "$ww * .15" | bc -l  | xargs printf "%1.0f"`
hh=`echo "$hh * .15" | bc -l  | xargs printf "%1.0f"`


if [ "$hh" -gt "$ww" ]
then
    let ww=$ww*2
fi

#year=`echo $dim | awk '{print substr($4,1,4)}'`
# works only if exif is avaiable..
year=`jhead "$1" | grep 'File date' | awk '{print substr($4,1,4)}'`

# i have images takin in range from 2004 to 2012, so if some exim data is removed, use year 2019..
case "$year" in
'2004')
    #
;;
'2005')
    #
;;
'2006')
    #
;;
'2007')
    #
;;
'2008')
    #
;;
'2009')
    #
;;
'2010')
    #
;;
'2011')
    #
;;
'2012')
    #
;;
*)
    year=2019
    mv "$1" "${bgp}2019"
    echo -ne "!"
    exit 0
;;
esac



if [ ! -f ${bgp}${year}.png ];
then
    convert -gravity southeast -size 300x130 xc:transparent -font Courier-bold -pointsize 125 -fill red -draw "text 0,0 '${year}'" ${bgp}output.png
    composite  ${bgp}output.png ${bgp}fons.png ${bgp}${year}.png
    #echo "${year}.png not found, create one ..";
fi

Watermark=${bgp}${year}.png


Fname="${backgroundimage##*/}"
Fdir="${backgroundimage:0:${#backgroundimage} - ${#Fname}}"
#echo "${Fdir}new_$Fname"
#echo "${ww}x$hh $1"
if [ ! -d "/media/sf_test/resize/$year/" ] 
then
    mkdir "/media/sf_test/resize/$year/"
fi

if [ ! -d "/media/sf_test/apstradatie/$year/" ]
then
    mkdir "/media/sf_test/apstradatie/$year/"
fi

if [ ! -f "/media/sf_test/resize/$year/$Fname" ]
then
    composite -gravity southeast \( $Watermark -resize ${ww}x${hh} \) "$backgroundimage" "/media/sf_test/resize/$year/$Fname"
fi
mv "$1" "/media/sf_test/apstradatie/$year"
#"${Fdir}neew_$Fname"

echo -ne "."
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do the following:

Create the logo in a bigger size, so you can scale it down later

Then loop through all images:

1. Get image size of image:

   $size_array = getimagesize ( $image_src );

   $width = $size_array[0];

   $height = $size_array[1];
2. Depending on image size, scale a copy of logo down
3. Compose logo over image